# Sqlite/android: insert actually replaces rows

Tags: android, sqlite, bulkinsert

In Udacity's Developing Android Apps, the app they're building displays the weather forecast in a listview, after fetching the data from the openweathermap api. The data is saved into the db via the function bulkInsert shown below. Updates are called by the option "Refresh" in the menu.

No code handles the pruning of old data, and yet the number of rows remains constant in the db after each refresh. Turns out that the last 14 old rows vanish after the loop inserting the 14 new rows. The latter have new row id's.

Example:

We start with:

```
_id=55
_id=56
_id=57
…
_id=721
_id=722
_id=723
_id=724
_id=725
_id=726
```

Following the bulk insert, the id list becomes:

```
_id=55
_id=56
_id=57
…
_id=735
_id=736
_id=737
_id=738
_id=739
_id=740
```

With the rows 713-726 missing/replaced. Code for bulkinsert:

```
@Override
public int bulkInsert(Uri uri, ContentValues[] values) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (match) {
        case WEATHER:
        db.beginTransaction();
        int returnCount = 0;
        try {
            for (ContentValues value : values) {
                normalizeDate(value);
                long _id =  db.insert(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, value);
                if (_id != -1) {
                    returnCount++;
                    Log.i(“id:”, " "+_id);
                }
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return returnCount;
    default:
    return super.bulkInsert(uri, values);
    }
}
```

insert is the vanilla SQLiteDatabase method, which is not supposed to mess with existing rows. Yet, when the line is commented out, the old rows remain in the db.

Any clue what's going on?